# Scala class - how to "forget" constructor args

Tags: scala

My class receives constructor arguments and converts them in a more "compact" representation.

I want the original constructor's arguments to be gathered by the garbage collector, but the Scala class still holds a reference to the constructor's arguments. How can I force it to "forget" them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the constructor arguments are only used in the constructor, and not declared as var or val, they will only exist as constructor arguments and not become fields on the class.

You could also, instead of a constructor create a companion object with an apply method or other factory method to instantiate your class.

Comment: Implementing an `apply` method is a good solution. And your statement about constructor arguments _when only used_ in the constructor is correct. Nonetheless, it's important to note that constructor arguments can be used in method definitions (or anonymous functions), in which case they would be stored as instance fields even if they aren't declared as `val` or `var`.